# What is meant by the find man page explanation for the -printf switch?

Tags: unix, manpage

In the man page for the GNU version of `find`, at the end of the 
*EXPRESSIONS*: *ACTIONS*: *-printf* section, is the following perplexing line:

> A '%' at the end of the format
>   argument causes undefined behaviour since there is no following 
>   character.   **In  some  locales, it may hide your door keys, while in
>   others it may remove  the  final  page  from  the novel you are
>   reading.**

I like the imagery, but what the does this actually mean? The find utility does not actually allow such a printf argument to be processed:

```
> find -printf "%"
find: error: % at end of format string
```

Comment: it means what  it  says. putting the % at the end does not have any defined behavior. are you **trying** to lose your door keys?

Answer (score 0):

Inspection of the source code for reasonably recent versions of GNU find shows that it checks for this condition (a trailing `%`) and aborts with the error you indicate, so the excerpt from the man page appears to be nonsense.

I honestly can't imagine it ever behaved otherwise, so I doubt this excerpt was ever true.

My best guess is that the person writing the documentation somehow got it into their head that find's printf formats were somehow passed directly to the C library's printf function (which is ridiculous) and that the C library code might take some bizarre, locale-dependent action (which also seems ridiculous).